# Master/details query with details in a list object

Tags: linq

In my Sql database I have tables `Orders` and `Details` following this model, where `Details.order` is a foreign key to `Orders.id`:

```
public class Order {
  public int id { get; set;}
}

public class Detail {
  public int id { get; set;}
  public int order { get; set; }
  public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to form a join query to return order-details in a flat list, for example:

```
from order in db.Orders
  join detail in db.Details on order.id equals detail.order
  select new { order = order.id, detail = detail }
```

The result is flat in that if there are 10 `Details` items, the result will have 10 rows.

How do I construct a Linq query to return the result similar to the class `OrderDetail`?

```
public class OrderDetail {
  public int orderId { get; set;}
  public List<Detail> details { get; set;}
}
```

where all the `Details` items of an `Orders` are in one list as a property of an `OrderDetail` object.

Answer (score 1):

You should do group join here. You can try the following code here:

```
  from order in db.Orders
  join detail in db.Details on order.id equals detail.order into OrderDetailsObj 
  from detail.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new { orderId = order.id, 
                      details = from od in OrderDetailsObj 
                                     select od.detail
              }
```

Comment: There are some typos in your answer, but `join .... into OD select new { order = order.id, details = OD }` works, when the source is a POCO object. With Sql it results in a 
`could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly ...` error. I have resolved it with another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880186/where-is-client-evaluation-needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an anonymous object, you should use your `OrderDetails` model for selecting records.

You can consider the following example:

```
var result = db.Orders
               .Select(i => new OrderDetails {
                 orderId = i.id,
                 details = i.details.ToList()  // this will be the ICollection of Details table
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't `i` of type `Order`? There is no `Order.details` property.

Comment: If you are using the code-first approach, you can add `public virtual ICollection<Details> DetailsNavigation { get; set; }` in your `Orders.cs`. This will help you access details based on the foreign key you already have.