# Where is client evaluation needed?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a query which works fine in Linq to Objects in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k19Z9f):

```
var list = from order in orders
             join detail in details
             on order.id equals detail.order into od
             select new { order = order, details = od };
```

I tried applying the same query when the data is in a database (note I am mapping Linq to Sql manually):

```
public class dbContext: DbContext {
   public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Detail> Details { get; set; }
   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder oB) {
     oB.UseSqlServer("...connection string...");
   }
}

using (var db = new dbContext() {
  var list = from order in db.Orders
               join detail in db.Details
               on order.id equals detail.order into orderDetails
               select new { order = order, details = orderDetails };
}
```

The above gives:

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I tried `details = orderDetails.ToList()` in the last line but the same error is there. Where should I add the manual client evaluation?

---

Some background information: the following database query (without the `into`) works fine:

```
var list = from order in db.Orders
            join detail in db.Details
            on order.id equals detail.order
           select new { order = order, detail = detail };
```

Comment: This requires a lot more detail, like exact EF version and class model. We need to see how the classes are mapped to the database. Another question is why you don't use a navigation property.

Comment: I am using the latest EF Core version. I am using EF very simplistically and manually, not generating code automatically using Model First or Database First methods. My database is an existing one, and Linq queries on the database work fine with the `Order` and `Detail` classes shown in the fiddle until I started dabbling into the `into` clause. My code works if I retrieve a flat list of joined orders details, but I wanted to return the details of an order into a `List` object to facilitate downstream work.

Comment: All of which we don't know when we read your question. You have to add that kind of info (which you should know, having been around for such a long time). Anyway, this is just another case of lacking `GroupBy` support in EF core. See the many questions in this area. Use a navigation property so you can query `order.Details`.

Comment: "Cannot be translated" means there's something in the query which can't be parsed or evaluated for use in a SQL query. I usually get this when I try to have it parse datetime information but linq can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a join you should declare [Navigation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) and use something like:

```
var query = from order in db.Orders
  select new { order = order, details = order.OrderDetails };

var list = query.ToList();
```

or simply

```
var list = db.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderDetails).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but first I have to set up a navigation property as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships.